# How to get gas amount web3py?

Tags: python, blockchain, ethereum, web3py

I can get the gas price, but how do I even get the gas amount? I feel like this is something that is not covered properly in the docs. In order for me to send a transaction(contract call), I need to build it but when I build it I need to give it the gas price and the amount of gas. How can I give it the amount of gas if I have no idea how to estimate the amount of gas?

For example this is my code of an approve contract call.

```
    tx = contract.functions.approve(spender,max_amount).buildTransaction({
        'nonce': nonce,
        'from':self.account,
        'gasPrice': web3.toWei('20', 'gwei'),
        'gas': ?
        })
    signed_tx = web3.eth.account.signTransaction(tx, self.pkey)
```

I can give it some arbitrary number, but this is not a real solution. In every example I see online, some arbitrary gas amount is thrown in, with no explanation of how they got it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `web3.eth.estimate_gas` on the unsigned transaction and then update the transaction with appropriate gas amount and sign

> ```
> tx = contract.functions.approve(spender,max_amount).buildTransaction({
>    'nonce': nonce,
>    'from':self.account,
>    'gasPrice': web3.toWei('20', 'gwei'),
>    'gas': '0'
>    })
>
> gas = web3.eth.estimate_gas(tx)
> tx.update({'gas': gas})
> ```

Comment: Is this code from somewhere else? Why is it quoted with no source given?

Comment: And what is "temp" here?

Comment: Sorry, temp should have been tx. I'll edit it

Answer (score 1):

- get the gas price : `w3.eth.gas_price`

```
transaction = SimpleStorage.constructor().buildTransaction(
    {
        "chainId": chain_id,
        "gasPrice": w3.eth.gas_price,
        "from": my_address,
        "nonce": nonce,
    }
)
```

- get the estimate gas

  ```
  estimate = web3.eth.estimateGas({
    'to':   'to_ddress_here', 
    'from': 'from_address_here', 
    'value': 145})
  ```

Answer (score 1):

From the [web3py docs](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/gas_price.html):

> Gas price strategy is only supported for legacy transactions. The London fork introduced `maxFeePerGas` and `maxPriorityFeePerGas` transaction parameters which should be used over gasPrice whenever possible.

Try building your transaction like this, setting only those fields. Web3 will calculate the best gas price using those constraints.

```
tx = contract.functions.approve(spender, max_amount).buildTransaction({
    'from': self.account,
    'maxFeePerGas': web3.toWei('2', 'gwei'),
    'maxPriorityFeePerGas': web3.toWei('1', 'gwei'),
    'nonce': nonce
})
```